# PC Completely Freezes, Needs to Be Rebooted

Tags: windows-7, memory, cpu, freeze, bsod

I have a pretty old built PC that I was recently upgrading. I upgraded quite a few different parts so I'm not sure what was the thing that lead to this issue but now my computer reliably freezes whenever I use it. The time of use before a freeze seems pretty random but it typically doesn't last more than a couple of hours. When I say freeze, I mean that nothing is responsive on the computer, CTRL+ALT+DLT doesn't respond and even the lights on my RGB keyboard stop moving. If there is sound going when the freeze occurs, typically whatever the last noise was will just play at a constant rate. The only thing that I have been able to do to get it back is to physically hold down the power button till is shuts off and then it comes back up without issue.

From my earlier statements, I talked about upgrading which is the Delta here so I'm sure that somewhere in there lies the issue. I first got a new graphics card, a Gigabyte Windforce 760. I have ensured that I have the latest drivers for that and everything is plugged into it correctly. I didn't have that in very long before I swapped more components so I don't really know if freezes happened right after this. Next, I got a new CPU and RAM at the same time. I have since taken out my old RAM and have in only the new RAM where at first I had added the new to the old to double the memory amount. As for the CPU, I upgraded to an 8-Core AMD. From much of my other research, temperature has been an issue but I have a pretty good cooler on it and lots of case airflow. My temps from "SpeedFan" never really seem to climb above 45 from my monitoring.

I have performed an entire clean install of Windows of this PC because in my trying to fix this issue and fiddling with things, I broke some registry values which were really screwing things up. I have tried many things to get this fixed but I am pretty much stuck and now at the point of looking at buying an entirely new rig, which I can't even afford right now so I'm willing to work to test out any debugging and troubleshooting routes that you have to suggest. Also, I just remembered that in between some of the complete freezes, there have also been BSODs. I don't remember what they said but they do happen every once in awhile.

I seriously and sincerely appreciate any and all help with getting my computer back to a working fashion.

Thanks!!

Comment: You'll need to provide more specific information to get assistance, starting with the basics - windows version, anything that induces the failures, actual hw components make/ model and details on the crashes. See this site for info on how to look at your event logs and find the pertinent info: http://www.howtogeek.com/222730/how-to-find-out-why-your-windows-pc-crashed-or-froze/

Comment: freezes mostly comes from either rams or gpu. Check them and use only one ram for now, and unplug everything that is connected to your computer via cables except your keyboard and mouse, until you fix this problem. also, provide your mobo, cpu, rams, gpu specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you got BSOD that is either memory corruption or bad drivers. I don't really think you get BSOD because of temperature, the computer just shutdown on those cases.

I would start by resetting BIOS to factory defaults, as the most common cause for memory error is overclocking or custom voltage. Reset and change everything to "auto" values.

If that does not solve it, remove the video card, and re-install the system*. Do not install ANY driver. nothing. network, video, nada. if it still happens, remove the new ram. If removing the new RAM resolves, return it. it is bad. If not, it is the new CPU, return it. then, all you have left is your video card. Run without the driver, then with the driver and see when it fails. You can try an older version of the driver too.

`*` instead of re-installing windows, just download some linux live-CD or live-USB image and run that directly from the media. you don't even have to touch the data on your HD.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a whole whole lot for all the suggestions and troubleshooting steps. Yeah, sorry about the lack of information. I would usually put some more in there but it was a moment of hurried laziness before I went on a long trip. Now that I'm back, I did actually realize that I made the stupid mistake of keeping the new RAM in instead of going back to the old RAM that I knew worked without issue. I swapped them out this morning and my PC has been running for a couple of hours without issue. I still don't feel 100% in the clear but I do believe that the new RAM was my issue which makes sense because my symptoms pointed to memory issues. If the problems come back up, I'll perform the steps that y'all provided. Again, thanks for the help on what looking at now was a pretty crappy post haha!